# Take string from data-bind inside a link

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to JavaScript and I am having this issue. Maybe I am asking something very dumb but I can't find a solution.

I have this:

```
<div class="text" id="title" data-bind=" text:display >
</div>
```

I need to take the string from data-bind, replace the spaces for a `+` symbol and and put it inside a link.

I need something like this:

```
<a href="path/index.php=q?%22 "Here the string" %22 " target="iframe2">click</a>
```

So like this I end up creating a search link with the value of data bind.
Also I need to target `iframe2` because my site is divided into two iframes.

I hope somebody can help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you're using knockout, why not use the [`attr`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) binding?

```
<a data-bind="attr:{href:'path/index.php?q='+encodeURIComponent(display())}">click</a>
```

Another option is to provide your own bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.customLink = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){
        var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.href = 'index.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(val);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext){
        var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        element.href = 'index.php?q=' + encodeURIComponent(val);
    }
};
```

Then you'd use:

```
<a data-bind="customLink:display">click</a>
```

Comment: thanks so so much for your time! I really apreciate your help.

Comment: I used attr binding and works perfect. And also I understand now how knockout works.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it!  And you're very welcome.  ;)